# Pocket PC/Windows Mobile: How to detect smart minimize

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, pocketpc, minimize

How do I detect when my Compact Framework application is being smart-minimized (smart minimize is what happens when the user clicks the "X" button in the top-right corner on a Pocket PC)?

The Deactivate event isn't the right way because it occurs in circumstances other than minimization, such as when a message box or another form is shown on top of the main form. And the form's WindowState doesn't help because there is no "Minimized" WindowState on .NET CF.

I heard that by setting MinimizeBox = false, my app will be closed instead of minimized. But I actually don't want my app to close, I just want to know when it has been minimized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the way to go here is processing the [WM_ACTIVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922525.aspx) message and then checking if the fMinimized parameter is not zero. You can find more information on how to declare this messages in your code in [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/WindowsMessages.html).

I will try figure out how to exactly code this in C# and prove the hypothesis. However you maybe faster than me and figure it out.

Also check the functions [DefWindowProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms960018.aspx) and [WindowProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms915527.aspx), which are used to process the messages. Functions are declared in your code like this:

First have the include:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

then in the class declare like this

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, UIntPtr wParam,
   IntPtr lParam);
```

---

There is another thing you could do, this is more a "philosophical" workaround. INMO the smart minimize X is confusing for users, that is why I don't like to include it. Instead I provide a button at the right lower corner of the form that says "close" or "back", which uses the close method of the form. I used it in all forms to keep a standard. This is less ambiguous for windows users because they may assume that the X in windows mobile is the same X in windows for PC.

If for some reason you need to minimize your app or send it to the background use the following code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...

public partial class Main : Form
{
   public Main()
    {


        InitializeComponent();
    }

  [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

  const int SW_MINIMIZED = 6;

  ...
  ...

   public void HideForm()
    {
        ShowWindow(this.Handle, SW_MINIMIZED);
    }
}
```

Comment: The **Compact Framework** does not give access to the `WindowProc` method for normal `Form`s, so how can I make use of this advice? Or am I missing something here...

Answer (score -1):

What exactly do you mean by smart-minimized? I suppose you mean your app being automatically minimised on no activity for some time? Well, I don't think that there is an event for that.

The author of this [blog spot](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowsmobile/archive/2005/08/03/447404.aspx) uses the Deactivate event for turning internal process on and off. This is acceptable for animation and other similar processes and the cases of a message box or another form popping up are no problems. If however, your process must not be stopped unless the application closes or 'smart-minimizes', you could try starting a timer on deactivate events. If the form isn't activated back for a specific interval, then it would be safe to stop the internal process.

Of course in designing your solution you need to take Power Management into consideration. Have a look at [this](http://#) and of course also OpenNetCF for power notifications.

Comment: Smart minimize is what happens when the user clicks the "X" button in the top-right corner on a Pocket PC. A related issue is how to detect the difference between the user starting another program and a dialog popping up that belongs to my application (both produce a Deactivate event).